# Callback after 2 html content load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to load 2 separate contents and then open up a balloon div to the page. both the contents take 1 seconds to load. So I open the div on 2nd contents load function's callback.

```
$("#term").load("/static/page/terms.html");

$("#term-realtor").load("/static/page/terms-realtor.html", function(){
   $("div#balloon").fadeIn(500);
});
```

my problem is most of the time 2nd content take more time to load than 1st one. But sometimes 1st one take longer than 2nd one. And then balloon div starts to show up even thought 1st content has not finished loading. My question is how can I call the callback after both finish loading? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to load both URLs in sequence or in parallel?

Comment: Use the ajaxStop event.

Comment: in paraller @Felix Kling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the two calls in parallel, I suggest to use [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) with [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
$.when(
  $.get('/static/page/terms.html'),
  $.get('/static/page/terms-realtor.html')
).then(function(response1, response2) {
  $('#term').html(response1[0]);
  $('#term-realtor').html(repsonse2[0]);
  $('div#balloon').fadeIn(500);
});
```

There are other ways of course, you could add a callback to the `$.get` calls and set the HTML there. To learn more about promises, have a look at the [**jQuery tutorial**](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/).

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$("#term").load("/static/page/terms.html", function(){
      $("#term-realtor").load("/static/page/terms-realtor.html", function(){
       $("div#balloon").fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
```